# Prevent some models from being indexed with Tire in a Rails app

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I have a searchable `Item` model in my Rails app.

I want to index the majority of those in ElasticSearch, EXCEPT the ones that fulfill some condition.

How can I do that?

Is overriding `update_index` in the model an acceptable solution?

---

I know I could also index them all, and filter them out in the search. But they will never be searchable so I don't see a reason for indexing them at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest thing is to handle the indexing hook yourself, as stated in the [README](https://github.com/karmi/tire):

> Notice, that you may want to skip including the Tire::Model::Callbacks module in special
>   cases, like when your records are indexed via some external mechanism (...) or when you
>   need better control on how the documents are added to or removed from the index:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search

  after_save do
    update_index if state == 'published'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Karmi. Actually someone answered and pointed me to a github thread where you discussed this issue, but he deleted his answer I guess.